# Outlook process can't exit

Tags: c++, outlook

I'm working on an application (a separate .exe) that communicates with MS Outlook (2007 & 2010) and captures some events. With Outlook 2010 everything works fine, however with Outlook 2007 I have noticed that when I close Outlook only the window is being closed, Outlook process  keeps running. Before showing any code, I'd like to know if someone knows where would such behaviour come from?
N.B, when I close my application Outlook process is stopped.

this [link](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/outlook-exe-continues-running-after-you-exit-outlook/) talks about a similar issue

***UPDATE***

e.g:
Here is how I'm capturing application events : (In my main thread)

```
CAppEventListener m_pAppEventListener = new CAppEventListener();
m_pAppEventListener->Initialize();
```

Here is how Initialize method is defined :

```
void CAppEventListener::Initialize()
{
    COleException l_oleExcep;
    BOOL bResult = m_OutlookApplicationInternal.CreateDispatch( _T("Outlook.Application"),&l_oleExcep );
    //m_LogTrace = new CLogTrace();
    //m_LogTrace->OnStartup(TRUE, TRUE);

    if ( !bResult )
    {
        //CString l_csError;
        //l_csError.Format("0x%08lx",l_oleExcep.m_sc);
        //m_LogTrace->WriteLine("\tERROR\tEchec lors de l'appel de \"Create Dispatch\" code erreur "+l_csError);
        //m_LogTrace->WriteLine("\tINFO\tFermeture d'IAOutlookMonior");
        exit(0);
    }

    AddRef();
    HRESULT hr = AttachToSource(m_OutlookApplicationInternal.m_lpDispatch );
    //m_LogTrace->WriteLine(_T("\tINFO\tSuccès de connexion à Outlook"));
}
```

And here is the AttachToSource method

```
STDMETHODIMP CAppEventListener::AttachToSource
                         ( IUnknown* pEventSource )
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    IConnectionPointContainer* pCPC = NULL;

    hr = pEventSource->QueryInterface( IID_IConnectionPointContainer, (void**)&pCPC );

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pCPC->FindConnectionPoint( IID_ApplicationEvents, &m_pConnectionPoint );
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = m_pConnectionPoint->Advise( this, &m_dwConnection );
        }

        pCPC->Release();
    }

   return hr;
}
```

`CAppEventListener` implements the `IDispatch` interface. And the `m_OutlookApplicationInternal` object is an instance of `CApplication` class.
How should I deal with it?

***UPDATE 2***

If my application process is killed (accidentally) before releasing the references to outlook objects, Outlook will keep running isn't it? how should I deal with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you do not keep outstanding references to any Outlook objects for any prolonged periods of time - make all variables local to a method, create an instance of the Outlook.Application object, etc. As soon as you are done, release all objects (Marshal.ReleaseComObjects if you are using .Net works great).

Comment: Thanks @Dmitry, and what about capturing event, shouldn't I keep a reference to an application object alive? I've updated my question

Comment: Even if I manually close my application process Outlook process keeps running after I close it

Comment: That means you are leaking a reference. Since you are using C++, nothing is automatically released unless you are using smart pointers. Try t co comment out most of your code and brink it back a few lines at a time until the problem comes back.

Comment: Ok @Dmitry I'll try it. What confuses me is that this doesn't occur with Outlook 2010

Comment: Starting with Outlook 2010 MS got fed up with this problem (outstanding references prevent Outlook from exiting), so now Outlook exits even if there are outstanding references. Which creates a whole new set of problem when you do *not* want Outlook to exit.

Comment: I'm still fighting with this issue but I couldn't solve it, I tried to release all the objects I explicitly created, I tried using smart pointers but Outlook still doesn't exit. Is there a workaround to deal with it? thanks in advance.
e.g: for the code I gave how to do to properly release com objects

Comment: The problem is that I'm capturing outlook events and I need o keep a reference to some outlook objects in order to receive the events.

Comment: Are your tracking the Application.Quit event?

Comment: Does that event fire?

Comment: Do you release all of your Outlook objects when it fires?

Answer (score 2):

Outlook is still running because you still have references to Outlook objects, so it is running in order to service any requests your application may make.

You need to count the number of windows (Explorers and Inspectors) that Outlook has open. This number is available from the Outlook object model.

When this number reaches zero your application should quit.

Alternatively there is an Application_Quit event. You should handle that event and quit when it occurs.

Comment: I thought of that too, but my application shouldn't quit when the Quit event is raised because I'm capturing Send/receive events too, and, you know, Outlook quit event can be raised before the SyncEnd one, as a consequence I may not capture when the send/receive operation ended.

Comment: Why do you need to capture every event? Rather I suggest you write the application so that it can catch up and cope with missed events.